# How to determine the Patch Level of a RedH at Enterprise Linux (RHEL) Installation?

Tags: rhel

We have RHEL6 installed on our server. I can see in the /etc/redhat-release that we have RHEL 6.9 installed.

**What I cannot figure out is:**
How do I find out what Patch Level is installed on our RHEL OS?

Comment: Use google, see instructions here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26432940/how-to-check-patch-level-on-linux-redhat.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I know, Red Hat Enterprise Linux does not have a patch level concept.

The closest thing to a patch level is an update/release. You can get it with:
`cat /etc/redhat-release`.

As found out by @sgrover, a more detailed output can also be found with the following command:
`rpm -qf /etc/redhat-release`

Comment: After a lot of searching, and trying - I found the following answer: `rpm -qf /etc/redhat-release
redhat-release-server-6Server-6.9.0.4.el6.x86_64
` - So here, 6.9.0.4 is the thing I was looking for.

Comment: Ok, this give you a more detailed version. I'll add this

Answer (score 0):

To obtain release and update levels, you can use `lsb_release`.  This is the "Linux Standard Base" command and is quite useful in scripts.  You may need to install it:

```
yum install redhat-lsb
```